# JQuery - combine toggle hover with on

Tags: jquery

How can I combine toggle hover with on event? The code:

```
img.on('hover', function(){
            name = $(this).attr('title');
            function(){
              $(this).parent().append('<figcaption>' + name);
            },
            function(){
              $(this).find('figcaption').remove();
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split it into `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`:

```
img.on('mouseenter', function() {
    name = $(this).attr('title');
    $(this).parent().append('<figcaption>' + name);
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $(this).find('figcaption').remove();
});
```

which is what `hover` wraps into a single function.

Comment: It is working, but for some reason it is not removing **figcaption**. Any idea why?

Comment: Working :). It also can work with **parent()**. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: you probably have to do `$(this).parent().find('figcaption').remove();`

Comment: You are appending figcaption to the parent, but for remove you are trying to find figcaption as a descendant of the img. `$(this).parent().find('figcaption').remove()` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You're not closing the `figcaption` element, you're just appending some random string with a starting element and some text, create it as a jQuery object instead. Also, the figcaption element is appended to `this` parent, which would make it a sibling and not a child, so `find` inside `this` will not find it, you'd either have to look for a sibling or search in the parent element (which should be a figure element):

```
img.on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        var name = $(this).attr('title'),
            figcaption = $('<figcaption />', {text: name});
        $(this).parent().append(figcaption);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $(this).parent().find('figcaption').remove();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

`.on()` can only have one callback function. So you will have to specify both `.on('mouseenter', ...)` and `.on('mouseleave', ...)` to mimic the .hover() behavior with .on().

Comment: And why is that! Can't you just pass multiple events in an object to `on()`.

Comment: It's because of the way .on() is implemented. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ There is no way to provide an object for the `handler` argument